# Wordpress Domain redirects to different host

Tags: redirect, migration

I wanted to move my wordpress site from Bluehost to InMotion. I did so by copying all files from public_html from my Bluehost server to InMotion. Under wp-config I changed database info etc. Then, in Wordpress I changed the Wordpress Adress (URL) and Site URL under "Settings -> General" to my new domain and was able visit my site using my new domain I bought with InMotion.

I think something went wrong though. I have completly deleted every from my InMotion server and did a fresh re-install of wordpress. That worked fine! However, when I now want to visit my old site, still on Bluehost, it always redirects me to my new domain/wordpress install. Im assuming it wasnt correct to change the Wordpress Adress and Site URL but I cant even get back into the backend to change it back, I am always redirected to my new wordpress install.

All files are still on my Bluehost server.

Comment: 301 redirects are cached by your browser. Even if the settings on the server(s) have changed, you still need to clear your local cache or test in a private browsing/incognito window.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to go directly to the database, via your cPanel. More often than not, you **can still** navigate to http://[yourdomain]/cpanel, even if you've 301'd your site.

From there, you should be able to find the `wp_options` table and set the domain record again.

Failing that, what's Bluehosts policy on rolling backups? Are you able to ask them to restore a snapshot from yesterday (much easier than messing with the DB yourself)?

Good luck!